# LibraryFunctionLoad with swift library

Tags: librarylink

I'm trying to figure out if there is any sane way to call a swift function using the LibraryLoadFunction.

In Swift it seems possible to use @_cdecl to get a c callable dynamic library.

When I test this with the simplest case I can think of: adding 2 integers and returning the answer I get an error:

LibraryFunction::rterr:
An error with return code 446408866 was encountered evaluating the function
add.

Comment: "C callable" is not enough. You need to have your function conform to LibraryLink's calling convention, i.e. it needs to take a specific set of arguments, which must be read in a specific way. Are you already comfortable with creating a LibraryLink library in C?

Comment: I was hoping it was something like ctypes in Python, where as long as you know the function name, parameters, and return type you're good to go. I'll try plain old C 1st.

Comment: I've tried with swift on windows, using -emit-library. Swift produces a .dll but the symbol is not exposed so maybe you should check if the symbol is _actually there_ and C-callable in the library at all. Reading around, one way to export a swift function is using an objective-C wrapper. This swift code will not cut it and will not produce a symbol you can use:

`@_cdecl("swadd")
func swadd(a: Int, b: Int) -> Int
{
 a + b
}`

Comment: `DefineDLLFunction` allows calling arbitrary functions from a shared library, at least on Windows. I have not used it in ages, and cannot comment on it. I do not know if it will work on non-Windows platforms. The new `FunctionCompile` might or might not enable similar functionality. I am not familiar with it enough to tell (maybe currently it doesn't do this but in the future it will?) Classic LibraryLink would require you to write a C wrapper which handles the communication between your function and Mathematica.

Comment: This is on macOS and I also used -emit-library. The symbol is there as if I just create a function that prints a string I capture the string in Mathematica but also get a type error.